# Python encoding problem (unicode)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Before throwing tomatoes, let me explain my problem (I have read the python unicode doc first).

I use json module to parse a json-format result into dictionaries. This, gives me unicode encoded strings (ex : u"My string t\xf4t"). Then I use Mysqldb to store this string in my Mysql database. I precise that these database is configured for utf8.

Then I retrieve my Mysql record, still using MysqlDB. Now my result printed looks like "My string t\xf4t" (without the u).
As I need to compare the inserted and the retrieved strings, I have to tell python my retrieve string is unicoded.

No matter what I try, I have a UnicodeDecodeError. I tried to play with the encoding : unicode(storedInDB, "utf_8") and with the errors param ("replace"). But I still have exceptions.

Do you have hints ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you call `MySQLdb.connect`  with `use_unicode = True`?

Comment: I forgot to look at this (I had the same problem few months ago with java and jdbc...). You solve it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, what you want to do is add `charset='utf8'` to your `MySQLdb.connect()` call.

For MySQL itself, character sets are set separately in many different contexts - most notably, for both table storage and for connections (and MySQL unfortunately still seems to default to latin-1 in many cases). So, you can - for example - go to the trouble of setting your entire database to use UTF-8:

```
CREATE DATABASE somedatabase DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

And yet, when you connect a client, MySQL may still think you're communicating with it in some other encoding:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

A basic solution to this is to execute `SET NAMES UTF8` immediately upon connecting, before you do anything else:

```
mysql> SET NAMES UTF8;
mysql> show variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

However, in your case, this still isn't sufficient, because the python MySQLdb module itself also wants to be helpful and automatically encode/decode python's native unicode strings for you. So, you have to set the character set in MySQLdb. This is best done, as mentioned earlier, by passing `charset='utf8'` when creating your MySQLdb connection. (This will also cause MySQLdb to inform the mysql server that your connection is using UTF8, so you do not need to run `SET NAMES UTF8` directly)

Comment: Wow, that was more complicated than I thought. How long will it be before everything, everywhere, defaults to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

`u"My string t\xf4t"` is a Unicode string (its type is `unicode`), but `"My string t\xf4t"` is a bytestring (its type is `str`).

`unicode(storedInDB, "utf_8")` tries to decode the bytestring as UTF-8, but `"My string t\xf4t"` isn't valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that although you configured MySql for UTF-8, you didn't actually write UTF-8 data into it. You would have had to encode from Unicode to UTF-8 before sending the string.